# Who is this mathematician on the Fields medal?

Tags: mathematicians

On the Fields Medal, there is a  picture  of a human portrait.

Picture is given below:

[image]

Who is this mathematician on the Fields Medal?

I think  this  portrait may be an ancient Greek  mathematician.

Comment: It's Archimedes.

Comment: Archimedes . .  since in front of the face says 

Comment: The Greek letter just in front of the face do indeed spell "Archimedes", in some version of Greek.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal#Medal)

Comment: @janmarqz: in Greek, it is `Ἀρχιμήδης`.

Comment: @Bernard, I copied the capitals in that coin

Comment: In lowercase, it is `Aρχιμηδους`. It's an error.

Comment: @Bernard: It’s the genitive case of the name.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Are you sure it is genitive? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: I wonder why a genitive on a medal?

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Yes; see the inflection table [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%88%CF%81%CF%87%CE%B9%CE%BC%CE%AE%CE%B4%CE%B7%CF%82#Ancient_Greek).

Comment: @Bernard: It may be modelled on the coins of Hellenistic kings, which bore the king’s name in the genitive, perhaps signifying that they were in some sense his coins.

Comment: A quite ingenious explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal):

The medal was designed by Canadian sculptor R. Tait McKenzie.

- On the obverse is Archimedes and a quote attributed to 1st century AD poet Manilius, which reads in Latin: "Transire suum pectus mundoque potiri" ("Rise above oneself and grasp the world"). The date is written in Roman numerals and contains an error ("MCNXXXIII" rather than "MCMXXXIII"). In capital Greek letters the word ΑΡXIMHΔΟΥΣ, or "of Archimedes".
- On the reverse is the inscription (in Latin):

  CONGREGATI
  EX TOTO ORBE
  MATHEMATICI
  OB SCRIPTA INSIGNIA
  TRIBUERE

Translation: "Mathematicians gathered from the entire world have awarded [understood but not written: 'this prize'] for outstanding writings."

In the background, there is the representation of Archimedes' tomb, with the carving illustrating his theorem On the Sphere and Cylinder, behind an olive branch. (This is the mathematical result of which Archimedes was reportedly most proud: Given a sphere and a circumscribed cylinder of the same height and diameter, the ratio between their volumes is equal to 2⁄3.)

The rim bears the name of the prizewinner.